# How to print out a rpart tree result in text in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, rpart

You can easily print out an rpart tree result in text in R console with the following command.

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
print(fit)
```

And it prints out:

> n= 81
>
> node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
>         * denotes terminal node
>
> 1) root 81 17 absent (0.79012346 0.20987654)      2) Start>=8.5 62  6
>   absent (0.90322581 0.09677419)
>        4) Start>=14.5 29  0 absent (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
>        5) Start< 14.5 33  6 absent (0.81818182 0.18181818)
>         10) Age< 55 12  0 absent (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
>         11) Age>=55 21  6 absent (0.71428571 0.28571429)
>           22) Age>=111 14  2 absent (0.85714286 0.14285714) *
>           23) Age< 111 7  3 present (0.42857143 0.57142857) *    3) Start< 8.5 19  8 present (0.42105263 0.57894737) *

However, this does not work in Rshiny textOutput.
See the following Rshiny Code:

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      textOutput("distText")
    )
  )
)
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(rpart)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distText <- renderText({
    fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
    print(fit)
  })
})
```

If I run the above shiny APP, it give the following error:

> Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) :
>   argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `capture.output(fit)` to get the string outputted by the print function.
You might also want to change the `textOutput` in the `ui.R` to an `htmlOutput`. This allows you to have a multiline text output.

Code would be like this:
server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(rpart)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        output$distText <- renderText({
                fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
                paste(capture.output(fit),collapse="<br>")


        })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

        # Application title
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
                plotOutput("distPlot"),
                htmlOutput("distText")
        )
)
)
```